# В чем разница, какой из вариантов приемлемей?

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую текстовый редактор Sublime Text 3, вопрос в том, в чем разница.
В одном случаи так, в другом так. Во втором пробелы, а в первом не знаю как это обозначается

Вопрос еще в том, что во втором случаи мне не удается сделать отступы такими же как в первом, почему?

Знаю что в пайтоне пробелы в начале строчки не допустимы. А как это сказывается в js, на производительности и тд?

Answer (score 1):

Это [табы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). В вопросе что лучше табы или пробелы [сломано много копий](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B). В общем случае, предпочтительно придерживаться одного стиля отступов в рамках одного проекта -- либо только табы, либо пробелы.

Чтобы визуально табы были равны ширене четырёх пробелов, настройте в саблайме `View -> Indentation -> Tab Width: 4`. Саблайм может автоматически заменять табы на пробелы и пробелы на табы, почитайте об этом в их [документации](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/indentation.html).